# Branching Factor and Depth

Tags: algorithm, minimax

> **Question**
>
> A simple two-player game involves a pile of N matchsticks and two
>   players who have alternating turns. In each turn, a player removes 1,
>   2 or 3 matchsticks from the pile. The player who removes the last
>   matchstick loses the game.
>
> **A)** What are the branching factor and depth of the game tree (give a general solution expressed in terms of N)? How large is the search
>   space?
>
> **B)** How many unique states are there in the game? For large N what could be done to make the search more efficient?

**Answer**

**A)** I said the branching factor would be 3 but I justified this because the player could only ever remove up to 3 matches, meaning our tree would usually have three children. The second part with regards to the depth, I'm not sure.

**B)** N x 2 where N is the number of matches remaining. I am not sure how we could make the search more efficient though? Maybe introducing Alpha-beta pruning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A :
For the depth, just imagine what the longest possible game would look like. It is the game that consists of both players only removing 1 match in each turn. Since there are n matches, such a game would take n turns : the tree has depth n.

B :
There are only 2*N states, each of them accessible from 3 states of higher matchstick count. Since the number of matches necessarily goes down as the game goes on, the graph of possible states is a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph). A dynamic programming method is therefore possible to analyze this game. In the end, you will see that the optimal move only depends on `N mod 4`, with N the number of remaining matches.

EDIT : Proof idea for the `N mod 4` :
Every position is either a losing or a winning position. A losing position is a situation where no matter what you play, if your adversary plays optimally, you will lose. Similarly, a winning position is a situation where if you play the right moves, the adversary cannot win. N=1 is a losing position (by definition of the game). Therefore, N=2,3,4 are winning positions because by removing the right amount of matches you put the adversary in a losing position. N=5 is a losing position because no matter what admissible number of matches you remove, you put the adversary in a winning position. N=6,7,8 are winning positions ...  you get the idea.

Now it is just about making this proof formal : take as hypothesis that a position `N` is a losing position if and only if `N mod 4 = 1`. If that is true up to some integer `k`, you can prove that it is true for `k+1`. It's true up to `k = 4` as we showed earlier. By recurrence, it is true for any `N`.

Comment: Make's sense. How did you get the value for mod 4 though? I don't understand how you arrive at the 4.

Comment: I added a proof sketch of this. It is just about doing the observation and then proving it by recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

The state of the game at any time can be described by whose turn it is and the number of matches held by each player. After n moves there are 3^n possible histories, but for large n, many fewer than 3^n possible states, so you can save time by, for example, recognising that you are about to encounter a state that you have already encountered and worked out a value for before.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim - if this is Nim, or a variety of Nim, there are efficient strategies already worked out for it.